# Android debug error

Tags: android, android-build

I am new in android programming.

I got an error while trying to run my project as stated below. May you please help me?

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:buildInfoDebugLoader'.
```

> Exception while doing past iteration backup : Source C:\Users\Mbali\AndroidStudioProjects\Prototype\app\build\intermediates\builds\debug\10522583303570\classes.dex and destination C:\Users\Mbali\AndroidStudioProjects\Prototype\app\build\intermediates\builds\debug\10522583303570\classes.dex must be different

Comment: please share the command you are using to build your project and which IDE are you using (if any)

Comment: I am running project on android studio. Pressed the 'run' Button on android studio IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Just **clean** your project using Build -> clean project and **rebuild** it and then **run**